# Efficient way to Finding string in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

> You are given two strings, AA and BB. Find if there is a substring
>   that appears in both AA and BB.
>
> All the strings contain only lowercase Latin letters.

Above, you see [a question from hackerranck](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/two-strings). I wrote the following program to solve it:

```
T = int(raw_input())

for t in xrange(T):
    s1 = raw_input()
    s2 = raw_input()
    length1 = len(s1)
    length2 = len(s2)
    checked = list()
    if length1<length2:
        for letter in s1:
            if len(checked)== 26:
                break
            if letter in checked:
                next
            checked.append(letter)
            if letter in s2:
                print "YES"
                break
        else:
            print "NO"
    else:
        for letter in s2:
            if letter in checked:
                next
            if len(checked)==26:
                break
            checked.append(letter)
            if letter in s1:
                print "YES"
                break
        else:
            print "NO"
```

It worked correct before adding `if len(checked)==26: break`. I added this line to make it more efficient by checking each alphabetic letter only once and get rid of time-out error in the submitting process, but after adding this line, the answer of my program is wrong for some test cases. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
if letter in checked:
    next
```

[`next` is a *function*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) in Python. Using `if letter in checked: next` is a no-op, you could just as well have used `pass`, as that will just reference the function object and not call it. It certainly won't `continue` to the next loop iteration.

So *no matter what the outcome of `letter in checked` is, you continue to add `letter` to `checked`*. Since `checked` is a list, not a set, you'll be adding duplicates to the list and you end up with more than 26 entries quite easily.

Use:

```
if letter in checked:
    continue
```

and consider using a set for `checked` to make `in` membership testing an O(1) operation rather than O(N).

Speaking of sets, this is basically a *set intersection problem*; is there any single letter that appears in both `s1` and `s2`. You are correctly testing if the sets are disjoint; so use the [Python built-in set type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). This would in the worst case do an O(N * M) loop, but the looping is in C code:

```
print('NO' if set(s1).isdisjoint(s2) else 'YES')
```

By using [`set.isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) no new set is created, only a boolean is returned. `set(s1)` loops over all of `s1` to produce the set, `set.isdisjoint()` will exit early as soon as it finds a match, each match test is O(1) against the set.

You could see if swapping `s1` and `s2` based on length improves your timings for the test still:

```
if len(s1) > len(s2):
    s1, s2 = s2, s1
print('NO' if set(s1).isdisjoint(s2) else 'YES')
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I didn't got this: _consider using a set for checked to make in membership testing_. May I ask you to explain a little more about sets using a sample code or refer me to a article about it please?

Comment: @Abraham: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset and https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity; Python lists take O(N) time to test if an element is present, sets can do it in constant time.

Comment: @Abraham: so `checked = set()` to create the set and `checked.add(letter)` to add a new letter to that set. `if letter in checked: continue` to skip the loop because you already tested the letter.

Comment: Didn't realize `isdisjoint()` existed.  Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use sets and see if the intersection is greater than zero:

```
"yes" if set(s1).intersection(s2) else "no"
```

To avoid iterating over the entire list:

```
"yes" if any(c in s1 for c in s2) else "no"
```

Depending on the size of s1 and s2 you could possibly benefit from shrinking them to sets:

```
"yes" if any(c in set(s1) for c in set(s2)) else "no"
```